# Make wireless printer visible on rest of LAN

Tags: router, network-printer

I have a Brother wireless printer, connected wirelessly to a wireless router, as shown in the diagram below. Router 2 is wired to Router 1. I would like to be able to get access to the wireless printer with devices connected to router 1 (both wired and wirelessly), but don't seem to be able to see it.

**Diagram:**
Wireless Printer ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ Router 2 -------- Router 1 ------ Cable Modem

Can someone point me in the right direction?

For what it's worth, Router 2 is a Google Wifi router, and Router 1 is a Comcast router.

Comment: your options are: 1. connect it to router1, 2. disable firewall and NAT on router2, or 3. forward the ports your printer uses through the NAT wall on router2. Most commercial routers will not allow you to take option 2, and many printers use many network ports, making 3 somewhat problematic, but potentially viable. can you determine what ports your router is using?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do that(assuming you don't use cloud printing and prefer privacy) it is connect printer over wire or wirelessly to the network of router1. Those who are behind Router2 will still be able to access that printer. I always prefer wired connection if it possible, much less hassle.

P.S.
To avoid confusion in a future, set printer's IP as a static and point to this IP devices that stay behind router2

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have that setup?

If you can change it, place Router 2 in bridge and/or AP mode. This means that it just acts like a switch and wireless access point, while Router 1 handles all the DHCP/DNS/Routing. Router 2 would be extending Router 1, and since everything is on the same network, the printer should show up.

The other options is placing the Printer on a DMZ on Router 2.

Comment: Usually setup such as OP showed is used in small offices, this way office's computers and servers stay securely behind router2 and guests allowed to connect to a router1. Exposing printer to a "guests" network is Ok in such cases.

Comment: @Alex while segregating is good in a business sense, OP doesn't seem to be using that. Here they have the wireless on the secured router2, instead of router1, the opposite you suggest.

Comment: Almost all comcast's routers now are wireless too. So it's obviously up to particular setup needs, if office network should have own WiFi access and must be separated from guests then having two firewall/routers might be used. I's a good idea to setup DMZ for printer on router2 if you trust a printer is not part of Mirai's botnet :)

Comment: I'm not keen on my ISP having more control over my gateway device than I have. as such, I will always drop a firewall between my LAN and the ISP.